# Can I share a cookie with a subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, cookie

Suppose I want my site to be accessible at `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`.

Is it possible to set a cookie when visiting one domain so that it is accessible in the other?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, try setting the cookie for `.example.com` as domain. That way, the cookie will be valid for every subdomain of yours.

For example, PHP sessions would be like this: `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');`